# Inserting items into database with this logic doesn't seem to work the way i want it whatever I do

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a list of movies and I want the movie to be added into the database (exactly the watchlist table )when the user clicks "Add to my list" Button , until now everything works fine but in my case as shown below the item may has some duplicates in other sections and when the user clicks "add to my list" button, it doesn't change the button of the duplicates movies ,I want all duplicates to change to "remove from my list" but without adding them to database, it should add only one item.As Shown below the button circled in yellow must also change to "Remove from My List"  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxnl0.jpg)

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (btn.dataset.add) {
      // Call add item
      addItemToDB(btn);
    } else {
      // Call remove item
      removeItemFromDB(btn);
    }
  });

  checkItemExist(btn).then((itemExist) => {
    if (itemExist) {
      btn.parentElement.innerHTML = `<button onclick="removeItemFromDB(this)" data-add="false" class="remove-from-watchlist-btn">Remove from My List</button>`;
    }
  });
});

async function addItemToDB(btn) {
  // Check if item exist in DB
  checkItemExist(btn).then(async (itemExist) => {
    if (!itemExist) {
      //  Add Item
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("itemId", btn.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id);
      formData.append(
        "itemName",
        btn.parentElement.previousElementSibling.dataset.name
      );
      formData.append(
        "itemPoster",
        btn.parentElement.parentElement.firstElementChild.dataset.poster
      );

      const response = await fetch("request/addItem.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });

      const result = await response.json();

      if (result) {
        btn.parentElement.innerHTML = `<button onclick="removeItemFromDB(this)" data-add="false" class="remove-from-watchlist-btn">Remove from My List</button>`;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Item exist");
    }
  });
}

async function removeItemFromDB(btn) {
  checkItemExist(btn).then(async (itemExist) => {
    if (itemExist) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("itemId", btn.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id);
      formData.append(
        "itemName",
        btn.parentElement.previousElementSibling.dataset.name
      );

      const response = await fetch("request/removeItem.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });

      const result = await response.json();
      if (result) {
        btn.parentElement.innerHTML = `<button onclick="addItemToDB(this)" data-add="true" class="add-to-watchlist-btn">Add to My List</button>`;
      }
    }
  });
}

async function checkItemExist(btn) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("itemId", btn.parentElement.parentElement.dataset.id);
  formData.append(
    "itemName",
    btn.parentElement.previousElementSibling.dataset.name
  );

  const response = await fetch("request/itemExist.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  });

  const result = await response.json();
  if (result) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: You've tagged your question PHP, but the only code shown is JavaScript.

Comment: I solved the problem myself

Comment: If you think your solution will help future readers, your encouraged to answer it yourself in the Answer box below. If you don't, you can delete the question so that it doesn't sit waiting for answers.